# Changing template search location in Magento CMS

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I would like to have one of my CMS pages access a template that is in the frontend/default/[theme]/[plugin] directory.

My current code to access this template is this:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml"}}
```

This checks frontend/**base**/default/template/... Is there a variable type that checks for the template in the default folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess every time you add a new block you must specify the `name` attribute.

Just add it to your code.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="path/to/template.phtml" name="mycustomblock"}}
```

This will add the template from your current theme.

Reminder: If this is a custom block (not core/template), you may need to [whitelist it](http://blog.adin.pro/2016-02-25/magento-add-block-into-cms-page-and-add-permissions/).

This should work. ;)